# What is wrong with my unit test? C#

Tags: c#

So basically I am trying to run a unit test on one of the classes in my program, the method in the class works fine but for some reason I can't get the unit test to pass.

Here is my class:

```
public class Driver

{

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public String Start { get; set; }
    public String End { get; set; }
    public int Distance { get; set; }

    public Driver(DateTime date, String start, String end, int distance)
    {
        this.Date = date;
        this.Start = start;
        this.End = end;
        this.Distance = distance;

    }     

    public override String ToString()
    {

        return string.Format("Date: {0}, Start Postcode: {1}, End Postcode: {2}, Distance: {3}miles", this.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), this.Start, this.End, this.Distance);
    }

}
```

}
`

Here is my test class:

```
 [TestClass]
public class Driverdetailstest
{
    private Driver TestDriver;

    [TestMethod]
    public void DriverDataTest()
    {
        DateTime date = new DateTime(2017, 12, 15);
        string start = ("SR47BB");
        string end = ("SR47FY");
        int distance = 10;


        var expected = string.Format("Date: {0}, Start Postcode: {1}, End Postcode: {2}, Distance: {3}miles", date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), start, end, distance);




        TestDriver = new Driver(date, start, end, distance);
        Convert.ToString(TestDriver);




        Assert.AreEqual(expected, TestDriver);        


    }
}
```

Despite the strings coming back the same I get this error as the reason the test is failing.

```
Message: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<Date: 15/12/2017, Start Postcode: SR47BB, End Postcode: SR47FY, Distance: 10miles (System.String)>. Actual:<Date: 15/12/2017, Start Postcode: SR47BB, End Postcode: SR47FY, Distance: 10miles (TaxiTracker.Driver)>.
```

What is it I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You did `Convert.ToString(TestDriver);` but didn't assign it to a variable, just do `Assert.AreEqual(expected, TestDriver.ToString());`.

Comment: Much appreciated Blake, its crazy how my eyes had overlooked that so many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your unit test is that you are comparing `string` and `object`.
You should do either this:

```
Assert.AreEqual(expected, TestDriver.ToString());
```

Or this:

```
string testValue = Convert.ToString(TestDriver);
Assert.AreEqual(expected, testValue );
```